# MySQL Update table using select query with union gives every derived table must have its own alias error

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having an issue with a query that enables me to move product details from multiple tables into a single table. This is my starting query

```
UPDATE tbl_temp_color_pricing cp ,
(SELECT
SKU ,
pkID ,
pkSKU ,
pkBrand ,
pkCategory ,
pkClass ,
pkSuperCategory
FROM
(
    (
    SELECT
    sb.SKU ,
    pb.pkID ,
    sb.pkID AS pkSKU ,
    pb.pkBrand ,
    pb.pkCategory ,
    cat.pkClass ,
    cat.pkSuperCategory
    FROM SKU_Basic AS sb
    JOIN ProductBase AS pb ON(sb.pkProduct = pb.pkID)
    JOIN Categories AS cat ON(pb.pkCategory = cat.pkID)
    )
    UNION ALL
        (SELECT
                p.SKU ,
                p.pkID ,
                p.pkSKU ,
                p.p.pkBrand ,
                p.pkCategory ,
                p.pkClass ,
                p.pkSuperCategory
            FROM
                tbl_products AS p
            WHERE
                p.storeID = 2)

)) skuMatch
SET cp.matchSKU = skuMatch.SKU ,
 cp.pkID = skuMatch.pkID ,
 cp.pkSKU = skuMatch.pkSKU ,
 cp.pkBrand = skuMatch.pkBrand,
 cp.pkCategory = skuMatch.pkCategory ,
 cp.pkClass = skuMatch.pkClass ,
 cp.pkSuperCat = skuMatch.pkSuperCategory
WHERE cp.storeID = 2 AND cp.adminID = 7
```

So I add aliases to the queries as per the answers I have found so far like so:

```
...
    FROM SKU_Basic AS sb
    JOIN ProductBase AS pb ON(sb.pkProduct = pb.pkID)
    JOIN Categories AS cat ON(pb.pkCategory = cat.pkID)
    ) t1
    UNION ALL
        (...
            FROM
                tbl_products AS p
            WHERE
                p.storeID = 2) t2

)) skuMatch
```

and now I get

> Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 't2
>
> ```
> )) skuMatch
> SET cp.matchSKU = skuMatch.SKU ,
>  cp.pkID = skuMatch.pkID ,
>  ' at line 37
> ```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

Every previous answer I found here on SO in my research into this issue suggested that I needed to add aliases to both the sub queries, but that is not actually the case. Removing the alias from the 2nd subquery like so:

```
UPDATE tbl_temp_color_pricing cp , (SELECT SKU, pkID, pkSKU, pkBrand, pkCategory, pkClass, pkSuperCategory FROM
    (
        SELECT sb.SKU, pb.pkID, sb.pkID AS pkSKU, pb.pkBrand, pb.pkCategory, cat.pkClass, cat.pkSuperCategory FROM SKU_Basic AS sb JOIN ProductBase AS pb ON(sb.pkProduct = pb.pkID) JOIN Categories AS cat ON(pb.pkCategory = cat.pkID)
    ) AS originalData <-- this alias is required
    UNION ALL
    (
        SELECT p.SKU, p.pkID, p.pkSKU, p.pkBrand, p.pkCategory, p.pkClass, p.pkSuperCategory FROM tbl_products AS p WHERE p.storeID = 2
    ) <-- no alias required
) AS skuMatch
SET cp.matchSKU = skuMatch.SKU,  cp.pkID = skuMatch.pkID,  cp.pkSKU = skuMatch.pkSKU,  cp.pkBrand = skuMatch.pkBrand,  cp.pkCategory = skuMatch.pkCategory,  cp.pkClass = skuMatch.pkClass,  cp.pkSuperCat = skuMatch.pkSuperCategory
WHERE cp.storeID = 2 AND cp.adminID = 7
```

enabled the query to run without error.

Hope that helps anyone else encountering this issue.